# Jquery ajax strange error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to localize my strings by creating an xml file for each language then using ajax get like so.

```
var text = new Object();
$.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'english.xml',
        dataType: "xml",
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              console.log("Lets see the error...");
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
        },
        success: function(xml){
                $(xml).find('text').each(function(){
                        text[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).text();
                });
        }
});
console.log("Lets see the object...");
console.log(text);
```

I have added some console.logs to troubleshoot.
Here is a screenshot of the console.
[image: console]

So you see for some reason the request has failed.. any idea why?

english.xml simply contains:

```
<text id="call">Caller</text>
<text id="chat">Chatter</text>
```

Update:
Changed datatype to text and now getting success response but the 'text' object is not getting updated ?

```
var text = new Object();
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'english.xml',
        dataType: "text",
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              console.log(xhr);
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
              console.log(status);
              console.log(error);
        },
        success: function(xml){
                $(xml).find('text').each(function(){
                        text[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).text();
                });
                console.log(xml);
                console.log(text);
        }
});
```

Comment: Move the `console.log` call inside the `success` callback. Currently, it's running before the asynchronous call returns.

Comment: is english.xml in the same directory?  Also try setting adding <?xml version="1.0" ?> to the top of your xml

Comment: @JamesAllardice that doesn't matter, its clear from the first print statement that its being called in the error callaback.

Comment: @James Allardice have tried it, nothing in the success callback is running only the error callback is

Comment: @JonTaylor - My comment isn't a solution to the problem the question is asking about (hence the comment, not answer), it's a solution to a different problem with the code. The `console.log` call outside of the callbacks is never going to log anything other than the empty object created on the first line.

Comment: @Jon Taylor yes its in the same directory, you can see the error output has grabbed the data ok. I have added <?xml version="1.0" ?> but no change.

Comment: have you changed the response type as per my other suggestion in my answer?

Comment: @JamesAllardice if it is a synchronous call then the output after should be fine.

Comment: @JonTaylor - Yeah, good spot, I just noticed the `async: false` option! However, be aware that `async: false` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

Comment: removed the async: false option altogether and still same response..

Comment: try outputting the error from the error callback rather than just the response text

Comment: ahh it was showing parsererror, so i changed to text, see update in question.

Comment: well for xml documents it should be "application/xml" also you might try `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` with the encoding.  You should however get it working with the application/html rather than just text

Comment: @Jon Taylor i tried this that and still get error message: "No conversion from text to application/xml"

Comment: changed it back to xml to see the error message: "Invalid XML: <text id="call">Caller</text>
↵<text id="chat">Chatter</text>"

Comment: you dont have a root node wrapping them, you need to have a root node, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

to the top of your document.  I have a feeling since your telling it your return type will be xml it is expecting this and erroring when it doesnt find it.

Also shouldn't your response type be `"application/xml"` rather than just `"xml"` ?

Also you have async set to false, this means you are asking for a synchronous call.  Just incase you were wondering

EDIT:  I have edited since `application/xml` should really be used instead of `text/xml`

You also need to have a root node

```
<applicationCalls>
    <text id="call">Caller</text>
    <text id="chat">Chatter</text>
</applicationCalls>
```

You can call your root node whatever you like, just try and make it something that makes sense.

Comment: I have tried these changes, and also without the async set to false and still get the same response.

Comment: i have added a root node <english>
    <text id="call">Caller</text>
    <text id="chat">Chatter</text>
</english> but still getting same error, if i run it through an xml validator i get Can not find declaration of element 'english'.

Comment: It looks valid to me unless I'm missing something very obvious, the only reason it might not be valid is if it was checking against a schema, but I don't see why it would be in this case.